# javascript function inside jade

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I had difficult times writing js function inside jade. I always get the function is not defined error. Below is my code :

```
extends layout

block content
  script(src='/socket.io/socket.io.js')
  script.
    var scoket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000')
    var email = #{email}
    var userEmail = #{userEmail}

    function sendInvite(){ socket.emit('invite from', email, userEmail)}

  div(data-role = 'page')
    div(data-role = 'header')
      h1 #{title}
    div(data-role = 'content')
      form(action='/postSendInvite', method='post')
        input(type = 'hidden', name='_csrf', value='token')
        input(type='hidden', name='email', value=email)
        input(type='hidden', name='userEmail', value=userEmail)
        h1 #{email}
        button(type='submit', onclick='sendInvite()') Send Invite
    include partials/footer
```

please let me know what I did wrong

Comment: function is not defined? or `socket` is not defined? You have a typo, first `scoket` then later `socket`

Answer (score 1):

Notice that it has nothing to do with jade. Once Javascript is interpreted, jade has been already rendered as HTML, so the question is about define JS function in a HTML page.

The error is probably because you defined a "scoket" and you are using after that a "socket", which is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for pointing the typo out, but the problem is not the typo, it is saying the sendInvite() is not defined, I found the solution is write the function in a helper js file, then include the js file into jade